# To achieve all the functionality of this code in Before event

Tags: triggers, salesforce, apex

How will i achieve all the functionality of this code in before event, whether it is re parenting, updating, inserting or anything. So, here is the code which is working fine in every condition but what if i want to do all the same stuff in Before event.
Thanks

```
    //Trigger

trigger InvoiceProductTrigger on Invoice_Product__c (before insert, before update, after insert, after update, after delete) {
    if((Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate) && Trigger.isBefore){
        InvoiceClass.invoiceProduct(Trigger.new);
    }
    if(Trigger.isAfter && (Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate)){
        InvoiceClass.invoiceAmountUpdate(Trigger.new);
    } 
    if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isDelete){
        InvoiceClass.invoiceAmountUpdate(Trigger.old);
    }
    if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isUpdate){
        InvoiceClass.invoiceAmountUpdate(Trigger.old);
    }
}

//Handler class
public class InvoiceClass {
    public static void invoiceProduct(List<Invoice_Product__c> invProduct){
        for(Invoice_Product__c inv : invProduct){
            inv.Total_Price__c = inv.Price__c * inv.Quantity__c;
        }
    }
    public static void invoiceAmountUpdate(List<Invoice_Product__c> invProduct ){
        Set<id> invoiceIds = new Set<id>();
        for(Invoice_Product__c invPro : invProduct){
            if(invPro.InvoiceLookUp__c != Null){
                invoiceIds.add(invPro.InvoiceLookUp__c);   
            }
        }
        List<Invoice__c> invoices = [Select id, Total_Amount__c, (Select id, Total_Price__c
                                                                  From Invoice_Products__r)
                                     From Invoice__c where id in : invoiceIds];
        for(Invoice__c inv: invoices){
            inv.Total_Amount__c = 0;
            for(Invoice_Product__c invProd : inv.Invoice_Products__r){
                inv.Total_Amount__c += invProd.Total_Price__c;
            }
        }
        if(invoices != Null){
            update invoices;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't implement rollup triggers purely in `before` events - at least, not easily, and it's not clear why you'd want to. You cannot query your `Invoice_Product__c` records from an `Invoice_Product__c` `before insert` or `before update` trigger, because they haven't been committed to the database yet.

Consider using [Declarative Lookup Rollup Summaries](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries) to define rollups rather than writing rollup triggers from scratch.

Comment: i do agree with you, but the thing is that was my assignment which i did, but my manager asked me to do the same in before event with all the functionalities.